# Changing Row Colours based on Cell Value - Applying the same Cell Value if value is the same

Tags: excel, colors, cell, conditional-formatting

In Excel:

I have a list of items that I have ordered. 
At the beginning in the very first column I have the order number. This number consists out of the supplier name + the date when I placed the order (eg. `Supplier1.17-05-19` or `Supplier2.17-05-19` or `Supplier.23-5-19`)

I would like alternate the cell colour based on the different cell values. All items with the order number Supplier1.17-05-19 should have white background colour and all items with the order number Supplier2.17-05-19 should have grey background colour and so on and so on.

Whenever I add new items because I added a new order I would like these items to have the same background colour but a different one to the order number I placed before.

I already tried every possible solution I could come up with using conditional formatting but nothing worked.

Whenever I add new items because I added a new order I would like these items to have the same background colour but a different one to the order number I placed before.

Example:

```
-Supplier1.17-05-19 - White Background Colour
-Supplier1.17-05-19 - White Background Colour
-Supplier1.17-05-19 - White Background Colour
-Supplier2.17-05-19 - Grey Background Colour
-Supplier2.17-05-19 - Grey Background Colour
-Supplier2.23-05-19 - White Background Colour
-Supplier2.23-05-19 - White Background Colour
-Supplier3.23-05-19 - Grey Background Colour
-Supplier3.23-05-19 - Grey Background Colour
-Supplier3.23-05-19 - Grey Background Colour
-Supplier3.23-05-19 - Grey Background Colour
```

Comment: why is supplier 2 both white and grey? supplier 1 is only white and supplier 3 only grey?

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your question. This is simple because the colours are alternating in whenever the order numbers changes

Comment: The edit shows it clearly now...

Comment: I have got a couple of ways of doing this - will answer when I get time later on today.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Compare the current cell with the previous cell.

If different AND the previous cell is not already formatted, colour it grey.

If the same AND the previous cell is already formatted, colour current cell grey.

Unfortunately this can't be done using worksheet functions like CELL because it doesn't recognise conditional formatting.

**Method 2**

Count number of unique values from start of column and test if it is odd or even. This is easy to do in Google Sheets with the Countunique function, but in Excel you would need something like this:

```
=ISEVEN(SUM(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A$2:A2,A$2:A2,0),MATCH(A$2:A2,A$2:A2,0))>0)))
```

This does work for the test data, but fails if the same order number occurs again after another order number (i.e. they aren't sorted into blocks).

[image]

[image]

**Method 3**

Count the number of turns in the data i.e. the number of times the order number changes up to the current row and see if it is odd or even. So far I can't see anything wrong with this one:

```
=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A1<>A$2:A2)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear Tom, First and foremost a big thank you!! This is insane! Unfortunately I don have it quite working out. I am using your fire method and it does not fully work. could you explain what is happening in that formula? Ivyline.03-05-19
Ivyline.03-05-19
Ivyline.03-05-19
Ivyline.03-05-19
Decco.08-05-2019
Ferm Living.03-05-2019
Ferm Living .03-05-2019
Pottery Pots.08-05-2019
Pottery Pots.08-05-2019

Comment: Dear Tom, First and foremost a big thank you!! This is insane! Unfortunately I don have it quite working out. I am using your third method and it does not fully work. the last and first entry of every block has the wrong colour. could you explain what is happening in that formula? I am eager to learn. What are the " -- " right after the Sumproduct and what is this part " A$1:A1<>A$2:A2 " doing? Thanks again, I appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: I haven't got the test sheet in front of me now so I can't fully answer your question, but the things to note are (1) the ranges in the formula must match the ranges that you're formatting, so if it started in row 10 (say) you would have to change it to A$9:A9<>A$10:A10 (2) the -- changes the result of a comparison (true or false) to a number so sumproduct can add it up (3) $A1:A1<>A$2:A2 is comparing each cell in the range with the previous cell, so the result of the whole sumproduct is the number of times the current cell is not equal to the previous one.